# SQL Server Agent Job cannot access datafile

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-agent

I have a an SSIS solution that runs fine in BIDS.  However, once I try to deploy it to the server and execute through SQL Server Agent, it fails with:

```
Cannot access datafile...
```

Details:

server:  localhost that I built
sysadmin:  my local domain account is the sysadmin using Windows Authentication
filepath:  my local C:\Users\me\Downloads

I have tried mapping my login to a credential and using that credential as a proxy, but it still fails.

Can someone help with a step-by-step solution as to how to make sure the SQL Server Agent account has access to write and read files on my local file directory?

Answer (score 0):

look that：

[image]

What is the service account for SQL Server Agent? Is has privilege to access operation sytem?

Comment: "NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT"